# ESB 4.6.0 with Data server plugin - Not able to execute stored procedure with REF_CURSOR

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am working on MAC OS X - 10.7.5 with WSO2 ESB 4.6.0 and Data Service feature - 4.0.5

Java java version "1.6.0_37"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06-434-11M3909)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.12-b01-434, mixed mode)

I am trying to execute stored procedure with ref cursor.

Here is my DS

```
<data name="RZM">
   <config id="RZS_Data">
      <property name="driverClassName">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
      <property name="url">XXXX</property>
      <property name="username">XXXX</property>
      <property name="password">XXXX</property>
      <property name="defaultTransactionIsolation">TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</property>
   </config>
   <query id="TEST" useConfig="RZS_Data">
      <sql>call RT_PROC_GET_VERSION(:in_app_id,:in_version_id,?,?,?)</sql>
      <result element="Results" rowName="Result">
         <element column="app_url" name="app_url" optional="true" xsdType="string"/>
         <element column="out_message" name="OutMessage" optional="true" xsdType="string"/>
         <element column="out_err_message" name="out_err_message" optional="true" xsdType="string"/>
      </result>
      <param name="in_app_id" ordinal="1" sqlType="INTEGER" type="INOUT"/>
      <param name="in_version_id" ordinal="2" sqlType="STRING" type="INOUT"/>
      <param name="compare_from_id" ordinal="3" paramType="ARRAY" sqlType="ORACLE_REF_CURSOR" type="OUT"/>
      <param name="out_message" ordinal="4" sqlType="STRING" type="OUT"/>
      <param name="out_err_message" ordinal="5" sqlType="STRING" type="OUT"/>
   </query>
   <operation name="TOP">
      <call-query href="TEST">
         <with-param name="in_app_id" query-param="in_app_id"/>
         <with-param name="in_version_id" query-param="in_version_id"/>
      </call-query>
   </operation>
</data>
```

I am getting following error all the time

```
[2013-02-14 18:00:14,400] ERROR - DataService DS Fault Message: Error in 'CallQuery.extractParams', cannot find parameter with type:query-param name:in_version_id
DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: RZM
Location: /RZM.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: TOP
Current Params: {}

DS Fault Message: Error in 'CallQuery.extractParams', cannot find parameter with type:query-param name:in_version_id
DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: RZM
Location: /RZM.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: TOP
Current Params: {}

    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.CallQuery.extractParams(CallQuery.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.CallQuery.executeElement(CallQuery.java:177)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.CallQueryGroup.executeElement(CallQueryGroup.java:111)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.OutputElement.execute(OutputElement.java:89)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.operation.Operation.execute(Operation.java:71)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DataService.invoke(DataService.java:548)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.execute(DSOMDataSource.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.serialize(DSOMDataSource.java:110)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:691)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:562)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:875)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.serializeInternally(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:283)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.internalSerialize(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:245)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serializeAndConsume(OMSerializableImpl.java:193)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:74)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.submitResponse(PassThroughHttpSender.java:435)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:227)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.java:45)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:434)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:219)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
[2013-02-14 18:00:14,402] ERROR - PassThroughHttpSender Failed to submit the response
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: DS Fault Message: Error in 'CallQuery.extractParams', cannot find parameter with type:query-param name:in_version_id
DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: RZM
Location: /RZM.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: TOP
Current Params: {}

    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:78)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.submitResponse(PassThroughHttpSender.java:435)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:227)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.java:45)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:434)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:219)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'CallQuery.extractParams', cannot find parameter with type:query-param name:in_version_id
DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: RZM
Location: /RZM.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: TOP
Current Params: {}

    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.execute(DSOMDataSource.java:105)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.serialize(DSOMDataSource.java:110)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:691)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:562)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:875)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.serializeInternally(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:283)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.internalSerialize(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:245)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serializeAndConsume(OMSerializableImpl.java:193)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:74)
    ... 12 more
[2013-02-14 18:00:14,403] ERROR - ServerWorker Error processing POST request for : /services/RZM.SOAP12Endpoint/TOP
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Failed to submit the response
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.handleException(PassThroughHttpSender.java:496)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.java:45)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:434)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:219)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: DS Fault Message: Error in 'CallQuery.extractParams', cannot find parameter with type:query-param name:in_version_id
DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: RZM
Location: /RZM.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: TOP
Current Params: {}

    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:78)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.submitResponse(PassThroughHttpSender.java:435)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:227)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'CallQuery.extractParams', cannot find parameter with type:query-param name:in_version_id
DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: RZM
Location: /RZM.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: TOP
Current Params: {}

    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.execute(DSOMDataSource.java:105)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.serialize(DSOMDataSource.java:110)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:691)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:562)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:875)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.serializeInternally(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:283)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.internalSerialize(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:245)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serializeAndConsume(OMSerializableImpl.java:193)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:74)
    ... 12 more
```

I am not sure why I get this error. I am trying to execute DS with "TryIt" service. Input XML is  following

```
<body>
   <p:TOP xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:in_app_id>1296</p:in_app_id>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <p:in_version_id>2.2</p:in_version_id>
   </p:TOP>
</body>
```

The stored procedure definition starts with following

```
     create or replace procedure RT_PROC_GET_VERSION (in_app_id                in number,
                                                    in_version_id           in varchar2,
                                                    out_version_detail      out sys_refcursor,
                                                    out_message             out varchar2,
                                                    out_err_message         out varchar2)
    is
    begin
            open out_version_detail for
            select
                    app_url, switch_board_url, version
.
.

end RT_PROC_GET_VERSION;
```

Can you please help?
thanks
Abhijit

Answer (score 2):

I have been fighting with it as well
I spent some time debugging code and figured that the reason was 'null' for request in MessageContext.
So it leads to the fact that Axis2 transport configuration influenced it. And indeed, WSO2 ESB 4.6.0 comes with default pass-through http transport that doesn't create message body, that's why whatever you passed to the service didn't work.
So in order to make it work you need to reenable  alternative http transport (for example find and uncomment `org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.http.HttpTransportListener`) in `repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml`
This should solve you problem in expense of disabling path-through. Maybe there is way to configure the transports side-by-side on different ports (task for later)

One remark,normally you should keep ESB and DSS separately as the solve different tasks and need specific configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Abhijith,

Using "Named parameters" and "ordinals" (parameter ordering with numbers) both at the same time would lead to some problems in parameter extraction and assignment. I suggest you use either "Named parameters" option or "ordinals" (only ONE out of the two) uniformly to assign all your input parameter mappings. That would fix the problem.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this  call RT_PROC_GET_VERSION(?,?,?,?,?)

And in input mapping option list all the in and out parameter with ordinals.
Ordinal will be based on question mark.
And one thing is question mark present in above query should be same as present your stored proc.
After this from stored proc if any data coming list them in out parameter

Ex: if your resultset is bringing id and address then list these two in output mapping.
NOTE:input mapping name should be same as present in stored proc.